# Making DOM updates in millisecond intervals

Tags: reactjs, animation, dom, websocket, requestanimationframe

*Scenario*:
   I am building a realtime IoT dashboard that will update sensor readings in millisecond intervals (100ms).The readings are streamed over websockets.There is a central redux store which dispatches actions to update the state.

*Problem*:
   With a handful of sensors the UI is freezing possibly the browser re-painting is getting blocked (not sure).

I did a bit of research on browser fundamentals.Came across requestAnimationFrame(rAF) and an excellant talk [Jake Archibald at JSConf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0%20%22%22).There is a github issue [Should React use requestAnimationFrame by default](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11171) related to the same.

So my question is should I use rAF for millisecond dom updates or simply rely on react internals to update the DOM? For me the millisecond precision is crucial and can't afford to have any batching of changes happening with sensor data.

Whats the way forward ?

Comment: I understand that your data is coming across 10 times/s, which really isn’t that fast, but why the restriction on batching? Does it matter if every update is presented to the user if the data is relevant for such a short period of time?

Comment: @cwharris Yes I agree there is a question of visual perception when UI updates happen at very high frequency.But my requirement is to show the sensor reading as soon as it arrives with the shortest time to repaint.

Comment: With that requirement, requestAnimationFrame is probably your best bet. I’m wondering if you could use a web worker to receive the data, and use your rAf callback to sample and draw/update dom.

Comment: @cwharris But web workers are not allowed to modify the DOM since they run in  a separate thread.Correct?

Comment: You’ll need a way to synchronize, maybe something like this: https://codesandbox.io/embed/1yv9ol3n6q?codemirror=1

Comment: @cwharris How much of a difference can web workers make given that network calls are already handled by different threads from the main one? Or to reframe the question what advantage do I get by using a web worker?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173263/discussion-between-ninjaas-and-cwharris).

Comment: similar question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614510/bursts-of-data-redux-buffering-react-rerendering?rq=1

Comment: @ninjas your question states you “can’t afford to have any batching of changes”, but you’re pointing to an answer where the solution is literally batching of changes (the OP used bufferTime. denounce is the wrong operator entirely).

Comment: @cwharris Yeah batching was not originally intended,but just feel a need to look on the other side of the fence :)

Comment: React already batches updates from non-interactive events, but yes, batching is the most effective approach for your scenario. Perhaps next time you could ask about the pros and cons of different approaches rather than excluding options as part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11171), for non-interactive events React will process `setState` calls asynchronously. This means that the latest state will be rendered *as soon as possible*. This is as close as you can get to realtime in a browser.

If you attempt to draw every single web socket state update synchronously, you run the risk of back pressure. Generally speaking, back pressure occurs when the consumer dequeues items from a queue slower than the producer enqueues them. The buffer builds up over time, causing both a memory leak and an increasing larger delay between the item's original enqueue time and the item's dequeue time.

The ReactiveX site has a [good example of back pressure](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/backpressure.html) - the web socket being the `Observable`, and React's async rendering being akin to the `Sample` operator.

React's asynchronous rendering handles back pressure by sampling the latest provided state *at the time of rendering*, meaning updates to the DOM are made as quickly as possible. React will probably be faster than trying to handle DOM updates on your own, because it only updates according to state changes - it doesn't update every element every "frame".

You should probably trust React to render ASAP with the latest data, and if the web sockets messages are occuring to quickly for the UI thread to handle, then handle them in a web worker instead.

Comment: Note this issue talks about **future of React**, not about what React does today.

Comment: @DanAbramov notice how I didn't mention requestAnimationFrame. The issue talks about React's future, yes, but I was not referring to that.